# How to add a legend to matplotlib pie chart?

Tags: matplotlib, legend, pie-chart

Using this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html
 how could I add a legend to this pie chart?
My problem is that I have One big slice 88.4%, the second largest slice is 10.6%, and the other slices are 0.7 and 0.3%. The labels around the pie don't appear (except for the biggest slice) and neither the percentage values for the smaller slices. So I guess I can add a legend showing the names and the values. But I haven't found out how...

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Rayos X', 'RMN en solución', 'Microscopía electrónica', 'Otros'
sizes = [88.4, 10.6, 0.7, 0.3]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors, shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.legend(title="técnica")
# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I checked your code, and the `plt.legend()` creates a legend, just how you want it to be; maybe set the `loc="lower left"`, so it does not overlap with the relevant pieces of pie.

For me, the strings are displayed properly, besides the non standard chars - which might cause the problem that they are not displayed to you at all. Only the biggest slice and "Otros" do not contain special chars. Maybe also try to resize the figure, as they might be pushed out of the canvas. Please refer to [how to write accents with matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#accents) and try again with proper strings.

The percentages are not shown, because you did not set them to be shown. Please refer to the example posted by you, as you omitted `autopct='%1.1f%%'`which will plot the percentages. In this special case, I would rather not plot the percentages, as they will overlap just like the labels on the border, as some slices are too small. Maybe add these information to the legend.

Putting it all together (besides the special chars - I had some problems activating TeX), try the following code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = [r'Rayos X (88.4 %)', r'RMN en solucion (10.6 %)', 
r'Microscopia electronica (0.7 %)', r'Otros (0.3 %)']
sizes = [88.4, 10.6, 0.7, 0.3]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral']
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting pie chart]

Comment: i don't know if the `plt.pie` api has changed, but I needed to do `patches, texts, _ = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)` (needed to expect a 3rd return val https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html )

Answer (score 3):

You can change your legend following types-

```
best
upper right
upper left
lower left
lower right
right
center left
center right
lower center
upper center
center

state = stateData['State/UnionTerritory']
cases = stateData['ConfirmedIndianNational']
explode = stateData.ConfirmedIndianNational.apply(lambda x:x > 100)
explode = explode.apply(lambda x:0.2 if x == True else 0)
plt.title("Covid 19")
plt.pie(cases, explode=explode,autopct='%1.2f%%',shadow=True, radius=3)
plt.legend(state, loc="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]