# pandas pie chart plot remove the label text on the wedge

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, legend, pie-chart

the pie chart example on pandas plotting tutorial http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html generates the following figure:

[image]

with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y'])

f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    df[col].plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.2f', labels=df.index,  ax=ax, title=col, fontsize=10)
    ax.legend(loc=3)

plt.show()
```

I want to remove the text label (a,b,c,d) from both subplots, because for my application those label are long, so I only want to show them in legend.

After read this: [How to add a legend to matplotlib pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852215/how-to-add-a-legend-to-matplotlib-pie-chart), I figure out an way with `matplotlib.pyplot.pie` but the figure is not as fancy even if i am still using ggplot.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
for ax, col in zip(axes, df.columns):
    patches, text, _ = ax.pie(df[col].values, autopct='%.2f')
    ax.legend(patches, labels=df.index, loc='best')
```

[image]

My question is, is there a way that can combine the things I want from both side? to be clear, I want the fanciness from pandas, but remove the text from the wedges.

Thank you

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can turn off the labels in the chart, and then define them within the call to `legend`:

```
df[col].plot(kind='pie', autopct='%.2f', labels=['','','',''],  ax=ax, title=col, fontsize=10)
ax.legend(loc=3, labels=df.index)
```

or

```
... labels=None ...
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to remove the extra x and y on the left side of each plot?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094596/python-matplotlib-pyplot-pie-charts-how-to-remove-the-label-on-the-left-side) is a solution.

Answer (score 14):

Using pandas you can still use the matplotlib.pyplot.pie keyword `labeldistance` to remove the wedge labels.
eg. df.plot.pie(subplots=True, labeldistance=None,  legend=True)

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html):
`labeldistance`: `float` or `None`, optional, default: 1.1
The radial distance at which the pie labels are drawn. If set to `None`, label are not drawn, but are stored for use in `legend()`

In context:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123456)


import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(3 * np.random.rand(4, 2), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns=['x', 'y'])

df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(10,5), autopct='%.2f', fontsize=10, labeldistance=None);

plt.show()
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stpwl.png)