# Python matplotlib.pyplot pie charts: How to remove the label on the left side?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, pie-chart

I plot a piechart using pyplot.

```
import pylab
import pandas as pd
test = pd.Series(['male', 'male', 'male', 'male', 'female'], name="Sex")
test = test.astype("category")
groups = test.groupby([test]).agg(len)
groups.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True)
pylab.show()
```

The result:

[image]

However, I'm unable to remove the label on the left (marked red in the picture). I already tried

```
plt.axes().set_xlabel('')
```

and

```
plt.axes().set_ylabel('')
```

but that did not work.

Comment: I now see that Pandas does this by default, see [documentation/examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#pie-plot). But I don't know how to suppress that...

Comment: just for the record, the "label on the left side" is the Series name. It may be obvious from the code, but I guess leaving this comment may help google help us all and others finding this answer in the future.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could just set the `ylabel` by calling `pylab.ylabel`:

```
pylab.ylabel('')
```

or

```
pylab.axes().set_ylabel('')
```

In your example, `plt.axes().set_ylabel('')` will not work because you dont have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in your code, so `plt` doesn't exist.

Alternatively, the `groups.plot` command returns the `Axes` instance, so you could use that to set the `ylabel`:

```
ax=groups.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True)
ax.set_ylabel('')
```

Answer (score 8):

Or:

groups.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True`, ylabel=''`)

Answer (score 3):

Add label="" argument when using the plot function

```
groups.plot(kind='pie', shadow=True,label="")
```