# Removing column name when using df.columnname.value_counts(kind='pie)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've made a pie chart using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnname': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'maybe']})

df.columnname.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', figsize=(10,10))
```

Everything is how I want it to be except it has "columnname" floating vertically off to the left.

[image]

I've tried to find what that parameter is called in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html?highlight=pie#matplotlib.pyplot.pie), but can't figure out what it's called to take it out.

What is that parameter called, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: You did not provide any data, any figure, any code. We do not even know what is "floating vertically off to the left". How do you expect people to guess what you are referring to? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas pie chart plot remove the label text on the wedge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059862/pandas-pie-chart-plot-remove-the-label-text-on-the-wedge)

Comment: @Sheldore I updated with data, code and an image

Comment: Try: `df.columnname.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', figsize=(10,10), label='')`

Comment: @ScottBoston that did it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `label` parameter in plot.

```
df.columnname.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', figsize=(10,10), label='')
```

Or, this is the y-axis label, you can hide it using

```
ax = df.columnname.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', figsize=(10,10))
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
```