# Matplotlib Pie plot not showing labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plotted the pie chart using the (.plot) function. The pie shows no label, I tried giving labels through the labels parameter but the same blank pie is plotted. How do I add labels to the pie?
Code-

```
count=[6943,933,417,337]
xlab=['Everyone', 'Teen', 'Adult', 'Old']

dic={"count":count,
    "label":xlab}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)

plt.pie(df["count"],labels=df["label"])
plt.show()
```

[Pie chart with no labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tafqL.jpg)

Comment: Do you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858256/1740577)?

Comment: Could you please post a mcve?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sure, have a look

Comment: Need to add `plt.legend()` before `plt.show()`

Comment: I changed the style of the plot by using " plt.style.use("default") " and the labels were visible.